# Creating a dataframe for each sheet of a workbook in R

Tags: r

I want to create a for loop that will create a dataframe for each sheet of a excel workbook (Input_Data)

for example, df1 would correspond to sheet 1, df2 corresponding to sheet 2, etc.

```
this is what I have so far.

library(readxl)

for(i in 1:39) {
  df[[i]]= read_excel("Desktop/R_Plots/Input_Data.xlsx", sheet = i)
}
```

Comment: So what happened when you ran this? What's the question exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `df` first so that its members become accessible by `[[`(). You may use:

```
df <- list()
```